# Creating a PHP template page

Tags: php, html, templates

I want to create a reusable PHP template that allows me to insert custom blocks of HTML code in multiple locations for different pages.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="banner">
### INSERT BLOCK OF CUSTOM HTML HERE ###
</div>
<div id="main-content">
### INSERT A DIFFERENT BLOCK OF CUSTOM HTML HERE ###
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd want to have multiple pages using this template, with each page having its own custom HTML code for the "banner" and "main-content" divs.

What's the best way to do this? I've considered using a template engine like Smarty, but I'm concerned about the performance hit. My site is also really simple, so I don't know if a separate template engine is a good idea.

I'm aware I can just use multiple includes, like so:

```
< ?php include 'top.php' ?>
### CUSTOM HTML ###
< ?php include 'middle.php' ?>
### CUSTOM HTML ###
< ?php include 'bottom.php' ?>
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this? Especially if I have more than two different chunks of custom HTML code, as well as some custom variables (such as a page title string) for each page.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using the [PHP Include Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) like you stated above:

```
<?php include 'file.php' ?>
```

Alternatively if that doesn't meet your needs, you can use [jQuery .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to include separate pages. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
$("#header").load("header.html"); 
$("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To be honest if you are just trying to keep things simple, I'd use the include statement you seem to know a bit about already.